# Как реализовать работу с mp3 на сервере

Tags: php, mp3, actionscript

Вопрос такой - есть сайты по типа promodj и soundcloud и я хотел бы нечто подобное. То есть чтобы можно было с помощью AJAX закачать файл (виден прогрессбар) и потом на главной странице отображать трек более наглядно. Идеально как в soundcloud

Comment: мп3 плеер на флеше с частотной визуализацией ,флэш формы отправки с прогрессбаром есть,пхп скрипт обмена музыкой на сервере и аякс на экшнскрипт.Вопрос не форумный...Это на фриланс вам.

Comment: спасибо большое, в целом я могу сам всё сделать, т.к. денег нет всё равно нанимать кого-то, actionscript знаю на уровне чтобы начать проект такого рода.. то есть вы предлагаете всё делать на flash? а как насчёт маков тогда? им будет недоступно?

Comment: Для "маков" будет доступно. Проблемы будут в АйФонах и АйПадах. Единственный компромис, на мой взгляд - это HTML5. Посмотрите так же [uppod.ru][1] - бесплатный видео/аудио/фото проигрыватель на флеш/HTML5 с богатым API. При определенном навыке с JavaScript и JSON можно реализовать. Вот только на счет наглядного отображение частот - затрудняюсь...


  [1]: http://uppod.ru

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень полезный сайт.

Comment: Ох и пробовал я как-то сделать частотную визуализацию на AS, гы-гы. Можно психологическую драму снимать, начиная от декодирования на лету(а нужные данные только из RAW можно получить) и заканчивая надписью 'CPU Loading: 100%' в диспетчере задач в течение 10 минут) На php, к слову, результат еще хуже, даже не пытайтесь. Хотя таки осциллограмму записи на php я нарисовал, но каждый запрос заставлял комп жалобно выть. Про реалтайм забудьте сразу - это c/delphi/asm.

Comment: А КАК же это реализовано на soundcloud и php? через java?

Comment: Вообще вот я порылся и понял, что просто так они вряд ли расскажут все свои секреты) Но обилие всяко-разных json, flash, php, ruby в исходниках говорит о том, что ребята не брезгливые и эта штука вполне может быть и на asm написана) В общем, обратите внимание на компилируемые языки. Я пока хорошо знаком только со связкой delphi+bass.dll, такая wav-форма пару секунд рендерится. -- Да, если вам нужна _только_ картинка, могу тот скрипт php скинуть) не думал, что он кому-то когда-то понадобится)

Comment: > начиная от декодирования на лету(а нужные данные только из RAW можно получить) и заканчивая надписью 'CPU Loading: 100%' в диспетчере задач в течение 10 минут)

Зачем декодировать на лету, когда можно один раз заранее на сервере подготовить все необходимые данные для визуализации (см. ответ @Ведрусс) и просто скармливать их флешу?

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, так я про "чистый actionscript в реалтайме" говорил. Загрузка трека в память флэша, разбор и выдача результата. ЗЫ: вопрос "зачем" считаю некорректным =) Искал бы везде смысл - застрелился б лет в 12) Как делать "по-хорошему", я дальше написал, а яву забыл просто потому, что редко сталкиваюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Да если и делать не на довольно популлярном флеше, то надо делать на java, о существовании которого знают точно не все. Прогрессбары на jаvascript для отслеживания передачи файла... помнится, на майл.ру грузил музыку, вроде гуглохром снизу слева в URLbаr'е мне показывал, сколько процентов закачано на сервер... если почитать документации к браузерам, можно найти лазейку к этой штуке для javаscript. Но за меньшее время, ыы это на экшнскрипте сделаете.

А на java из загруженной мп3шки дискретную карту частот выбрать, записать в .тхт файл массив значений амплитуды звука, например, на каждую 3-ю секунду. Сохранить этот .тхт на серв, а плеером запрашивать вместе с мп3'шкой и анимировать колебания картинки, ориентируясь на значения массива из дискретной карты.

[[@Realetive](/users/1900/realetive)](/users/1900/realetive): я не говорил, что флеш непопулярен. Написано, если не на популлярном флеше, то на javа.

Answer (score 0):

Товарищи, Java существует! (теперь, надеюсь, "знающих" станет гораздо больше).
А про непопулярность флэша - это вы бабушкам рассказывайте, которые браузером не пользуются.

В HTML5 все теги аудио и видео поддерживаются полностью. Поддержка их вашим браузером - отдельная тема. У adiom встал вопрос о создании аудиоплеера, а не клиент-серверориентированного приложения. Не видел, чтобы Ipad работал с Java... А вот с HTML5 он работает вполне сносно - и ролики, и видео смотрю без проблем. Так что новый стандарт, на мой взгляд, свою задачу успешно выполняет - краткостью тэгов борется с избыточностью решений.